# Why does Airbus A380 have only reversers on inner engines?

Tags: airbus-a380

I have seen many videos, and I noticed that only the inner engine reverses were opened. Why not on the 4 engines?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/why-doesnt-the-a380-use-its-outboard-thrust-reversers?rq=1